# loadDataWithBaseURL shows black square instead of my html

Tags: android

I have in my app a section where I have a local html page that I want to display, but when I run this code, I see a black square instead:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
  String summary = "<html><body><h1>my html</h1></body></html>";
  browser.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, summary, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

now when I try to load a URL using:

```
browser.loadUrl(URL);
```

it works perfectly. my layout:

```
 <ScrollView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:fillViewport="true"
      >

      <WebView
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/webkit"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:padding="0dp"
          />

  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I'd start by removing the `ScrollView`. `WebView` already knows how to scroll. Beyond that, try ordinary `loadData()` instead of `loadDataWithBaseURL()`, since you are not providing or needing a base URL, and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare to what? linear? frame? I tried: `browser.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");` but no changes

Comment: Just get rid of it. Make your `WebView` be the root element, if there is nothing else in your XML: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/WebKit/Browser3/res/layout/main.xml

Comment: @CommonsWare it work now thanks, i think the loaddata and the layout fix did the trick